# How can I find English versions of these books by A. Suter?

Tags: book, early-modern, modern, switzerland, modernisation

Does anyone know if any of these books is available in English (either for purchase or free download)? If so can you suggest a corresponding website?

Suter, Andreas (1997): Der Schweizerische Bauernkrieg von 1653. Politische Sozialgeschichte – Sozialgeschichte eines politischen Ereignisses. [worldcat](https://worldcat.org/title/37340779)

Suter, Andreas (2004): Kollektive Erinnerungen an historische Ereignisse – Chancen und Gefahren. Der Bauernkrieg als Beispiel, pp. 143 – 163 in Römer, J. (ed.): Bauern, Untertanen und "Rebellen". [worldcat](https://worldcat.org/en/title/780137084)

I have searched through the Internet, but couldn’t find any.

I am not even sure what is the original language of those books. Guess it is German.

May be German-speaking members knowledgeable in early modern history can help me out with this?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Google Translate will tell you what language the titles are in. Searching in the relevant Amazon site will give you clues.

Comment: @JohnDallman, Amazon has only versions in the original language

Comment: I mean, if Amazon doesn’t list translated versions… perhaps a good excuse to learn German?

Comment: Indeed, that could be a enticing motive.

Comment: @JonCuster yes, I guess this would be an answer to my question